# Postgres dynamically creating listeners

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a web site, backed by a postgres database. There are multiple webservers, that maintain persistent connections to each client, and needs to notify them of relevant events. The changes from one web-server may effect a user that is connected to another web-server, so I need some messaging layer between web-servers. Ideally I'd like to use the database for this, to keep things simple.

So the two obvious ways, I see, would be:

1) Have the webserver listen to *all* events, and web-server side filter the ones that are useful to it (e.g. relates to the users it currently has a connection with).

OR:

2) Dynamically create a listener for each client that connects, and remove the listener when the client disconnections.

The first way means a *lot* of useless data going over the wire, but very easy for the webserver to filter (a simple hashmap lookup). The second way looks ideal **if** postgres is implemented in such a way that I can have thousands (to tens-of-thousands) of listeners created at any time.

BTW I'm using the latest version of postgres

Thoughts?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The simpliest (and most accurate) way to tell if postgres will be able to handel thousands of `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` is to set up a simple test that will emulate your production load.

Comment: BTW. You can also set up a single server, that will `LISTEN` and relay the events to the clients registered on it (directly or inderectly throu the web-server). Or use some kind of middleware message brocker.

Comment: 3. Have an `active_listeners` table and check that before emitting notifications.

Comment: Is your question about listening for events in PostgreSQL or transmitting events to the client?

Comment: Both really. Just want to know about the performance characteristics of having thousands of listen'ers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so to notify the client, you would have to use some sort of persistent, stateful connection, like a websocket.  There are a number of ways to address load and performance there so I won't discuss that too much as we don't  have a narrow enough area to discuss the implications and solutions.

For the database-side, "thousands" is still relatively small in number in database terms, and listeners don't affect the planner so I don't see any reason why this would be a problem.  However, there are three things to consider before you go this direction.

1. Number of database connections.  Certainly you don't want thousands of database connections.  That way madness lies.  If you are going to do thousands of listeners it should be to a relatively small number of connections.
2. This is an atypical use of listeners, leading to an atypical quantity.  Just because I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work doesn't mean you might not eventually run into problems.  I did some light-weight testing and didn't find any significant performance implications of ten thousand listeners.  I would expect a small amount of memory would be used for each listener and that even a sequential scan of the listeners table would perform well (and that it woudl be cached in memory anyway if frequently used).
3. LISTEN/NOTIFY provides very little security.  You probably want to couple this with some sort of tables storing the payload rather than pass it along in the payload of the notify statement.   Thousands of tables are more likely to cause problems than thousands of listeners, because the planner has to think about the number of tables in planning an SQL statement.

If I were to do this, I would set up a catalog of which clients each connection claimed, and set up one listener for that connection. I would also set up a single table for payload data, and since each connection would claim part of that table, you could effectively ignore concurrency problems on the db side.  Again that is just my solution.  There may be others.  I don't see any obvious problems to large numbers of listeners, but be aware you are heading into territory, if you go that way, which few have gone before.  My suspicion is that the number of listeners is likely to be the least of your worries, however.